# Need to get exact matching rows only

Tags: php, mysql

Here i have a query

```
 make           |  model | disc
 maruti suzuki     ritz     Y  
 maruti suzuki     swift    N
 maruti suzuki     swift    Y
 Hyundai           i10      Y
 Hyundai           i20      Y
 Hyundai           eon      N
 tata              indica   Y
 tata              nano     Y
 tata              safari   Y
```

i have tried with the below query

```
  select * from table_name where disc='Y' and disc!='N'
```

but i got the result like this

```
    make           |  model | disc
    maruti suzuki     ritz     Y  
    maruti suzuki     swift    Y
    Hyundai           i10      Y
    Hyundai           i20      Y
    Hyundai           i10      Y
    Hyundai           i20      Y
    tata              indica   Y
    tata              nano     Y
    tata              safari   Y
```

Here now i need all makes list that must having all models disc type Y

that means my output should be

```
 make              model   disc  
 tata              indica   Y
 tata              nano     Y
 tata              safari   Y
```

Comment: And? What is your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: What you have tried for it???

Comment: This is very basic google question, hint: `SELECT` and `WHERE`. __EDIT__ I retract my statement after author edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: here i need to get the below output as shown below

Comment: @DeDee i hope this is what you want to suggest right select * from table_name where disc='Y' and disc!='N'

Comment: Show us that you tried anything and SO can help you fix it, we don't provide free code.

Comment: It's better to give the solution rather than down vote for my question....i hope this is not soo basic question....i happy if any come with the solution

Comment: @vamshigoli It's better to do your own research and try to solve it on your own before coming here, SO is **NOT** a free coding service.

Comment: @DeDee i have tried with the below query
select * from table_name where disc='Y' and disc!='N'

Comment: @ Epodax common come with your solution....i know i have searched i could'nt get the desired solution so i have asked my question here

Comment: It's not a matter of being easier or not, it isn't the purpose of the community to provide ways for your goals, but solutions to your issues along the way you found most fit. When you put your cursor over the downvote button, it suggest that it must be pressed if the question shows **no research efforts** as it is your case. Said that, consider trying something, showing what you've tried and ask for help based on that.

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: @Aedix Rhinedale  now i have updated my question with what i have tried and what i have need

Comment: Ok, it's better! Now, your question's still not clear. What exactly do you want? All models from `tata` make where `disc` equals `Y`? Or all discs that are `Y` but have different models?

Comment: @ Aedix Rhinedale i need particular make with all disc Y i.e means for any make there is disc N it should not show in the result

Comment: And why, exactly, is `select * from table_name where disc='Y'` failing you?

Comment: Note that `where disc='Y' and disc!='N'` is redundant. If disc is "Y", then *obviously* is it not "N".

Comment: @AedixRhinedale I admire your patience, you might manage to salvage this question after all. :)

Comment: @vamshigoli Your question suggests that, either you need only `tata` make models, or only `Y` discs where `model` won't repeat. Is that right?

Comment: @ Aedix Rhinedale not tata make models if any make model haveing all Y then i need to get those records

Comment: Now I've got it! Did you try @FilipIonDorien answer already?

Comment: Yes,thanks for all your efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use a simple `WHERE` clause for this, nothing fancy:

```
SELECT * from cars WHERE make NOT IN (SELECT make FROM cars WHERE disc = 'N')
```

Here is a working **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2e88/5/0)**

Comment: Sorry this won't give the my result what i have shown

Comment: This query also fetch `maruti suzuki     ritz     Y ` that OP dosn't want

Comment: @vamshigoli run the demo

Comment: thanks this works for me

Comment: @vamshigoli If the answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as the correct one!

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE make NOT IN (SELECT make FROM my_table WHERE disc <> 'y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Query will Be:

```
SELECT  make, model, disc FROM your_table_name WHERE dics='Y'
```

Comment: Where is it different from `select * from table_name where disc='Y'` that OP's already said it won't fit his needs?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be.

```
select make, model, disc from table_name WHERE make NOT IN (SELECT make FROM table_name WHERE disc = 'N')
```

Comment: OP's question isn't clear enough for answers. He showed an expected output but with no clause for it.

Comment: sorry i should not take make in where condition